# How to pass the output of a function to another function in R?

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

So I want to pass the output of func1 to func2.

```
func1 <- function(x, y, z) {
    k = x*2
    j = y*2
    i = z*2
}

func2 <- function(x, y, z) {
    func1(x, y, z)
    m = k * j * i
    return (m)
}
```

It keeps printing errors.

Comment: Your func1 is not returning anything. Your func2 does not need the return(), just the m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few things going on here, and it really partly depends on if you are showing us a very simplified version.  For example, are you really doing the same thing to x, y, z in the first function or are you possibly doing different things?

First, the `i`, `j` and `k` vectors that you are creating in func1() do not exist outside of func1().
As @akrun said you could rectify this bye making them into a vector (if they are always of the same type) or a list and then returning that.

So then you could get, say,

```
func1 <- function(x, y, z) {
    k <- x*2
    j <- y*2
    i <- z*2
    c(k, j, i)
}
```

At which point you could a a parameter to your second function.

```
func2 <- function(x, y, z) {
   ijk <- func1(x, y, z)
   prod(ijk)
  
}
```

Of course even easier if you can vectorize func1() (but I don't know how much you simplified).

```
func1v2 <- function(x, y, z) {
   
    2* c(k, j, i)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution. This is called a `function factory` which means a function that creates another function. Since `func2` only uses the outputs of `func1`, it can find them through `lexical scoping` in its parent environment which is the execution environment of `func1`.
Just note the additional pair of parentheses I used in order to call the function since the output of the first function is a function.

```
func1 <- function(x, y, z) {
  k <- x * 2
  j <- y * 2
  i <- z * 2
  func2 <- function() {
    m <- k * j * i
    m
  }
}

func1(1, 2, 3)()
[1] 48
```

For more information you can read this [section](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html) of Hadley Wickham's Advanced R.

Answer (score 2):

We may return a named `list` from the first function and then access the `names` of the output of the first function using `with`

```
func1 <- function(x, y, z) {
    list(k = x*2,
    j = y*2,
    i = z*2)
    
}
func2 <- function(x, y, z) {
     with(func1(x, y, z), k * j * i)
  
    
}
```

-testing

```
func2(3, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `func2` only makes the product of a vector you do not need to define a second function. You can do it like this: First define func1 as you did

```
func1 <- function(x, y, z) {
    k = x*2
    j = y*2
    i = z*2
return(c(k,j,i))
}
```

Then use it inside the `prod` function like this

```
prod(func1(1, 2, 3))
48
```