# R- Inner functions variable issue

Tags: r, function, environment-variables, global-variables

I am writing some functions and I need help figuring out the workings of inner functions in R. I have this test R code:

```
func1 <- function(a, b) {
  l <- a * 10
  m <- b * 20
  func2 <- function() {
    n <- l * m
  }
  func3 <- function() {
    o <- n/2
    o
  }
}
```

It throws me an error saying *R object n* is not found when using the following code in the R console:

```
func1(a=1, b=2)()
```

Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong? I assumed when I call a variable within the same function, it should read in.

Also, is function call *func1(a=2, b=2) ()* the only way to call the function? I was thinking *func1(a=2, b=2)* should work. Any information on why I need to use these extra paranthesis () would be great. Thanks a lot.

Note: Please note, that I took a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69966948/how-to-pass-the-output-of-a-function-to-another-function-in-r), but my question would be an extension of the existing answer. Thank you.

Comment: `func3` doesn't know about `n` because it only exists inside `func2`

Comment: @DanAdams thank you. Is there a way to pipe **n** to **func3**? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues with your example. Here is a brief description and below I've fixed it up to work as I belive you intended:

1. It seems as if you may be mixing up the definition of functions with their execution. It's fine to define a function inside a function, but you probably want to also *call* that function, otherwise it won't do anything.
2. As written, `func2` assigns `n` which means `n` will *only* exist inside that function. Therefore `func3` can't access it. Instead you'll want to make the result of `func2` available to `func3` by assigning it *outside* `func2` after creating the function.
3. Without a `return()` statement, a function will return the last line executed. The last line of the outer function (`func1`) is defining `func3`. That means the output of calling `func1` isn't a value but a function. That's why you need to put the extra parentheses. Instead, you will want to actually *call* `func3` at the end of `func1`.

Here's the fixed up version:

```r
func1 <- function(a, b) {
  l <- a * 10
  m <- b * 20
  func2 <- function() {
    l * m
  }
  n <- func2()
  func3 <- function() {
    n/2
  }
  func3()
}

# demonstrate it works
func1(a = 1, b = 2)
#> [1] 200
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note, you could also define `func2` and `func3` separately and then just call them inside `func1`. For this to work you will want to define arguments for each rather than relying on accessing variables defined in containing functions by name:

```r
func2 <- function(l, m) {l * m}
func3 <- function(n) {n/2}
func1 <- function(a, b) {
  l <- a * 10
  m <- b * 20
  n <- func2(l, m)
  func3(n)
}

func1(1, 2)
#> [1] 200
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

**1)** If you want `func3` to be able to access `func2`'s variables then define `func3` in `func2`.  Also just defining a function does not cause it to run so run both `func2` and `func3`.

The only changes are the ones marked ## plus putting `func3` inside `func2`.

```
func1 <- function(a, b) {

  func2 <- function() {

    func3 <- function() {
      o <- n/2
      o
    }

    n <- l * m
    func3() ##

  }

  l <- a * 10
  m <- b * 20
  func2() ##

}

func1(a = 1, b = 2)
## [1] 200
```

**2)** Another possibility is to have `func2` inject `n` into `func1`.  Define `e` to be the environment in the running instance of `func1` and then just assign `n` into `e` using `e$n`.  Since `func3` is defined in `func1` it has access to `func1`'s variables.  As in (1) we must call `func2` and `func3`. ## marks the changes.

```
func1 <- function(a, b) {
  e <- environment() ##

  func2 = function() {
    e$n <- l * m ##
    func3() ##
  }

  func3 <- function() {
    o <- n/2
    o
  }

  l <- a * 10
  m <- b * 20
  func2() ##

}

func1(a=1,b=2)
## [1] 200
```

**3)** A third approach is to inject `func2`'s entire body into `func1` essentially turning `func2` into a macro.

```
func1 <- function(a, b) {

  func2 <- function() eval.parent(substitute({ ##
    n <- l * m
    func3() ##
  })) ##

  func3 <- function() {
    o <- n/2
    o
  }

  l <- a * 10
  m <- b * 20
  func2() ##

}

func1(a=1,b=2)
## [1] 200
```

**4)** What you are trying to do is essentially using object oriented programming through the back door.  We can define `func2` and `func3` as methods to a proto object `p`.  The first argument to a proto method is always the object.  `.$n <-` assigns `n` into the proto object and `func3` being a method of it can access it.

```
library(proto)

func1 <- function(a, b) {

  p <- proto(
    func2 = function(.) {
      .$n <- l * m
      .$func3()
    },

    func3 = function(.) {
      o <- n/2
      o
    }
  )

  l <- a * 10
  m <- b * 20
  p$func2()

}

func1(a=1,b=2)
## [1] 200
```

### Update

Have `func1` return a number rather than returning a function. Add (2), (3) and (4).

Answer (score 1):

If you change the function `func2()` to accept `l` and `m` as
arguments and then `func()` to have an agrument `n`, you can add calls to `func2()`
and `func3()` at the end of `func1()`.

```r
func1 <- function(a, b) {
  l <- a * 10
  m <- b * 20
  func2 <- function(l, m) {
    n <- l * m
  }
  func3 <- function(n) {
    o <- n/2
    o
  }
  func3(func2(l, m))
}

func1(a=1, b=2)
#> [1] 200
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I see that in *func3* you used arguments (l,m). I am looking for a way to use *n* in funct3. Do you have an approach for writing func3 arguments with only (n)? Thanks.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect that requirement.